# Simple sort algorithm for names - Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

If I have an array of objects **Array 1:**`[Object 1, Object 2, Object 3]` and each object looks like the following:

```
object 1 has properties : creation date, name, class, size where name = Bear
object 2 has properties : creation date, name, class, size where name = Dog
object 3 has properties : creation date, name, class, size where name = Guerilla
```

And I want to sort these objects based upon their respective names in alphabetical order, so **Array 2** looks like the following `[Object 1 (Bear), Object 2 (Dog), Object 3 (Guerilla)]`

how would I approach this problem in Javascript? Are there any convenience methods for doing this? I am relatively new to JS. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom comparer:

```
Array1.sort(function(x, y){
  var n1 = x.name;
  var n2 = y.name;
  return n1 == n2 ? 0
    : n1 < n2 ? -1
    : 1;
});
```

Comment: @Alnitak: That makes sense when you want an exact comparison. Here it doesn't make sense. If `2` and `"2"` are not considered equal, do you then want `2 < "2"` or `2 > "2"` to be true?

Comment: I think you mean "function", but I like this answer because of the explicitness of the code here...

Comment: @Derek: A method is a function that is a member of an object.

Comment: @Derek: Aha, now I see what you mean. Thanks, fixed it. :)

Comment: @Guffa no problem. I just wanted to make sure that anybody else that finds the post and copy/pastes this code doesn't pull their hair out wondering why the code isn't working. Again, great answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

Note that `sort` is an *in-place* sort, so your original array will be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript sort method accepts an anonymous comparison function that gives you all the flexibility that you would need to sort objects on any attribute.

The general pattern is:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){...});
```

The "anonymous" function provided to the sort method accepts two objects to compare, and should return a value that indicates which element to sort higher, as follows:

if a should be sorted higher than b, return 1
if a should be sorted lower than b, return -1
if a is equivalent to b (for sorting purposes), return 0

Here's an example (ellipses indicate other attributes):

```
var beasties = [
  {name:'Bear', created_at: ... },
  {name:'Dog', ... },
  {name:'Gorilla', ... }
];

beasties.sort(function(a,b){return a.name > b.name});
```

Here, I'm relying on the ability for js to compare the strings that are returned by the name attribute.

I think that ought to do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom compare function to Array.sort which will then be used by the sorting algorithm to decide which one of two array elements is larger. When the algorithm compares two objects, it passes these to the compare function. When the function returns 1, it considers the first one as larger. When it returns -1, it considers the second one larger. When it returns 0, it considers them equal.

```
 function compare_function(obj1, obj2){
      if (obj1.name == obj2.name) return 0;
      if (obj1.name < obj2.name) return -1 else return 1;

  }
  my_array.sort(compare_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort method of the array, and pass in a function:

```
Array1.sort(function(left,right) {
    if (left.name < right.name) return -1;
    if (left.name > right.name) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```